# sheet_to_json set range by columns using xlsx nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, excel, xlsx

I would like to know how to Read values only from specified range of columns
using xlsx sheet_to_json

In a excel, read values from D to J using xlsx nodejs

```
const XLSX = require("xlsx");

const workbook = XLSX.readFile("data.xlxs"); 
const worksheet = workbook.Sheets["data summary"]; 
       

const result= XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet,{range: "D:J", blankrows: false });;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use

```
const result = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet,{header: ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'], blankrows: false })
```

where array from 'header' option is the list of columns you want.

Use 'range' option to skip raws from worksheet start.